how to enable http2 in spring cloud gateway
My spring cloud gateway(SCG) with reactive stack has enabled http2.
server:
  port: 8080
  shutdown: graceful
  http2:
    enabled: true

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: id
          uri: https://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path= ...

It routes request to my webflux application.
My webflux also enabled http2
server:
  http2:
    enabled: true
  port: 8081
  shutdown: graceful

I checked both of application support http2 (with curl)
curl --http2-prior-knowledge localhost:8080/~~ -v
curl --http2-prior-knowledge localhost:8081/~~ -v

In this situation, i expected that the connection between SCG and webflux server is http2.
But it was http/1.1
// webflux server's netty log
2024-04-19 11:17:15,318 INFO  reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog : 127.0.0.6 - - [19/4월/2024:11:17:15 +0900] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 350 15

I don't understand why they're not communicating on http2 when they're both working on netty. Do I need something more setup? I need help thx
I expect

Why is it not http2 when routing from scg to webflux server
how to enable http2 in this situation (between scg and routine destination server)


Have you found a solution ?

Did you got chance to fix this
